# "From Email" doesn't work in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, email

This is my code:

```
Mail::send('view',$dataView, function($message) use ($user)
{
    $message->from('my_email@gmail.com', 'Myname');
    $message->subject('This is title');
    $message->to(sender_email@gmail.com, $user->user_username);
});
```

It works! But When I check sender_email@gmail.com then I see "from email" which I config in .env ( MAIL_USERNAME ), it isn't "from email" in code (my_email@gmail.com), How to I can change it to my_email@gmail.com? Thanks and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send emails via dynamic senders which is not allowed by `Gmail` for preventing spamming mails, so automatically `Gmail` will change your sender address to your default address.

Comment: Thanks your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In `config/mail.php`, around line 58, try changing:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => 'hello@example.com',
    'name' => 'Example',
],
```

to:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'name'    => env('MAIL_USERNAME')
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're misunderstanding the `MAIL_USERNAME` which is in your `.env` file.
So basically, Laravel provides simple solution to send emails via dynamic senders. Lets say you've signed up for [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) to send mails and `MAIL_USERNAME` is the username for your mail provider not your `sender` mail address. (Not Gmail, as Gmail doesn't support dynamic senders. Its good if you're testing your mails.).
so, you're `.env` will look like this.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sendgridUsername
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgridPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Now, you're eligible to send mails using sendgrid. Now Lets say your domain is `example.com` so you can use `admin@example.com` `support@example` or any email address with your domain to send emails.

To Receive messages either you use webmail or [Gmail](https://apps.google.com/products/gmail/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks your answer!